# Obtaining specific data from a very very long string unix

Tags: string, unix

I'm doing a script in unix for obtaining specific data, after running a program it gives as an output a very huge string, for example: (is just a random example)

```
In this example, the null scorex: 34;hypothesis of "marginal homogeneity" would mean there was no effect of the treatment. From the above data, the McNemar scorex: 687;test statistic with Yates's continuity correction is scorex: 9;
```

and I like that whenever it finds the string "scorex: " it gives me the actual score: 34, 687 or 9, for this example.

Thank you

I forgot, my string is inside a variable called RESULTADO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep`:

```
grep -oP 'scorex:\s?\K\d*' input
```

or

```
<command> | grep -oP 'scorex:\s?\K\d*'
```

For your example:

```
$ echo "In this example, the null scorex: 34;hypothesis of "marginal homogeneity" would mean there was no effect of the treatment. From the above data, the McNemar scorex: 687;test statistic with Yates's continuity correction is scorex: 9;" | grep -oP 'scorex:\s?\K\d*'
34
687
9
```

Comment: Can you send me a link in which I can find how this grep's option works? (specially the \s?\K\d*). I'm new to unix, but i have done a few tutorials, but no one gets to deep in grep. I want to learn =D

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved via a regex. Considering the following pattern:

```
scorex: (\d+)
```

Using this pattern with grep would look like this:

```
grep -Eo "scorex: (\d+)" file_containing_string | cut -d: -f2
```

The output of this is for every capture the result:

```
 34
 687
 9
```